# How to run grep on a single column?

Tags: grep, awk

I want to grep the output of my `ls -l` command:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 root root       1866 Feb 14 07:47 rahmu.file
-rw-r--r--   1 rahmu user     95653 Feb 14 07:47 foo.file
-rw-r--r--   1 rahmu user   1073822 Feb 14 21:01 bar.file
```

I want to run `grep rahmu` on column $3 only, so the output of my `grep` command should look like this:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 rahmu user     95653 Feb 14 07:47 foo.file
-rw-r--r--   1 rahmu user   1073822 Feb 14 21:01 bar.file
```

What's the simplest way to do it? The answer must be portable across many Unices, preferably focusing on Linux and Solaris.

*NB: I'm not looking for a way to find all the files belonging to a given user. This example was only given to make my question clearer.*

Comment: Note that [parsing the output of `ls` is inherently fragile](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) (think what happens if a user name contains whitespace — and yes, this happens on some platforms). Use `find` instead.

Comment: This doesn't answer the title question, but I'll mention that the `--printf` option to `stat` may come in handy in places where you might otherwise consider parsing `ls`.  But usually, `find` is what you want (as @Gilles mentioned).

Answer (score 70, accepted):

One more time `awk` saves the day!

Here's a straightforward way to do it, with a relatively simple syntax:

```
ls -l | awk '{if ($3 == "rahmu") print $0;}'
```

or even simpler: *(Thanks to Peter.O in the comments)*

```
ls -l | awk '$3 == "rahmu"'
```

Comment: Or: `ls -l | awk '$3=="rahmu"'` ...  and by the way, the  opening `(` bracket should be after `if` ... `awk '{if($3 ...'`

Comment: @Peter.O +1 from me. Your command is more succinct, correct, since print is the default for an awk match.

Comment: To avoid localization issues (date format affects column order) it is often suggested to ensure standard format and language: `LANG=C ls -l | awk ...`

Answer (score 27):

If you are looking to match only part of the string on a given column, you can use advice from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17001849/awk-partly-string-match-if-column-partly-matches

```
some_command | awk '$6 ~ /string/'
```

Comment: This should be the top answer

Comment: work great. thanks.

Answer (score 12):

If by column, you mean fixed-size column, you could:

```
ls -l | grep "^.\{15\}rahmu"
```

where `^` means the beginning of the line, `.` means any character and `\{15\}` means exactly 15 occurrences of the previous character (any character in this case).

Comment: One can also do `ls -l | grep -E '^.{15}rahmu'` because `-E` is defined by POSIX anyway and then you don't have to escape the command group character.

Answer (score 6):

I know I'm late to the party, but I believe a very general solution to this problem is to use awk with regular expressions like so:

```
awk '$3~/rahmu/{print}' input_file
```

The part enclosed by '//' can be any kind of regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

To grep based on single username column (and print only files), you can try:

```
ls -la | grep "^-\S\+\s\+\S\+\s\+rahmu"
```

For directories, change `-` into `d`, for any type remove `-`.

It basically selects each column by `\S\+\s\+` which matches a non-space characters followed by a space characters, so we're matching three first columns and then the username.